# How to solve problem that event listener doesn't work? and how to take input's text value?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple button submission with an eventListener but it doesn't work, can you troubleshoot it?
That's the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

And that's the code:

```
function getData() {
  console.log('Hello World! ');
}
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', getData());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are attaching the event to the element before the element is in the DOM. You can either place your code at the bottom of the *body* tag or attach the event inside [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event). This will ensure that the event will be attached to the element only after the DOM is fully loaded. Hence, the element will be available to access.

Also, you probably do not want the event handler function to be executed on page load, so you should remove the `()` after the function:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', getData);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This line of code

```
document.getElementById('submit')
```

returns `null`, as the error clearly says. So you need an element in your HTML with id `submit`.

```
<button id="submit">Click me</button>
```

Also note that your listener will execute the function right away, the correct way of writing it is

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', getData);
```

or preferably

```
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
     getData()
});
```

Comment: I have a button named submit

Comment: Maybe your code gets executed before the html is loaded. You can put the script at the end of the body tag to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, but if I want to read an input element's value?

Comment: You can do that the same way... `document.getElementById('myInputElement').value`

Comment: ok, just for some reason ```module.exports``` and ```require``` doesn't work for me....

Comment: That's a different question. If you use CommonJS modules from Node on your front-end code, you'll have to use a javascript module bundler.

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: You can use Parcel Bundler, RollupJS, Webpack, Snowpack, etc. to bundle javascript modules.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```js
submit.onclick = () => {
  // getData();
  console.log("clicked!");
}
```

```html
<button id="submit">Get Data</button>
```